# Why Request.Params Does not Like the Vertical/Pipe Bar |

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

When using Request.Params to extract a string variable from the view, strangely the request replaces the Vertical Bar with ^DXKS^. What is that conversion technique called? What DXKS stands for? and is this the only character that gets transformed?

Sending the parameter in this form to sql server would yield no match. How to fix this?

I know too many questions under one title but I could see them as a chain of thoughts.

Comment: Sounds like a weird defect to me. That's not any standard way of encoding that I'm aware of. Are you using a form post to do this? If so, can you verify whether the pipe character is being sent in the POST data from the browser? (I'm wondering if maybe some kind of JavaScript library on your page is trying to convert this character for some reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a "DevExpress-specific encoding" as described in [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T330458).